# Downloading a PDF file gives a "Network Error"

Tags: pdf, download, typo3, fpdf, fpdi

Im in a TYPO3 system and I have an extension where I built a PDF file using fpdf.

When I submit the form with the data, the file is downloaded (around 3MB file) but when the download reaches 100%, it gives me a "Unknown Network Error". (Thats the message in Chrome)

This is my extension: http://pastebin.com/8GQCcKWj

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution: Don't do a

```
return $pdf->Output('medienpass.pdf', 'D');
```

in your getPdf() function because the output will be wrapped up in a lot of html code.

Instead return only your pdf to the client:

```
die($pdf->Output('medienpass.pdf', 'D'));
```